# Location of the amd64 compiler in Visual Studio 2022 | Compiling FFmpeg with NVENC

Tags: visual-studio, ffmpeg, compilation, x86-64, nvenc

I'm trying to follow [Nvidia's guide to compile FFmpeg with nvenc support on Windows](https://docs.nvidia.com/video-technologies/video-codec-sdk/ffmpeg-with-nvidia-gpu/#compiling-for-windows) and it has a stage to export the path of Visual Studio's 2013 SP2 amd64 compiler to the global path variable of the compilation dev environment:

> export PATH="/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/BIN/amd64/":$PATH

They say earlier in the guide that for different versions of Visual Studio different path might be required. I'm trying to use Visual Studio 2022 Community, but don't know where its amd64 compiler directory is.
I also don't know what `that VC` stands for ("Visual C", maybe, whatever that "Visual" might mean?).

I found in the installation directory of Visual Studio 2022 a few directories named `amd64` but none of them were under one with `VC` or something similar in its name.
The one I think is the most likely candidate to be the updated compiler is at `<install-root>/MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64`.

If anyone knows, please tell me if if this is the right path, and if not, what is the right path.

Microsoft does offer a version of Visual Studio 2013 Update 2, though (I assume they changed their naming scheme from "service packs" to "updates, which would make it the same software), but it doesn't offer a 64-bit version of it, and I want to compile a 64-bit software - so I assume it doesn't come with one. Please do correct me if I'm wrong, it'd save me needing to use a version of Visual Studio that is different than the one in the guide.

Comment: I think @dingyong666 answer is correct for VS2022 latest.

Also you may find useful this:
> It is possible that coreutils' link.exe conflicts with MSVC’s linker. You can find out by running 'which link' to see which link.exe you are using. If it is located at /bin/link.exe, then you have the wrong one in your PATH.

from https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3203


> –-toolchain=msvc wrong spell before toolchain
when you copy from link 

from https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/problem-compiling-ffmpeg-with-nvenc-using-visual-studio-2015-community-edition/112540/6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is to refer to relevant documentation. The documentation for Video Codec SDK 11.1, [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-video-codec-sdk/download), which FFmpeg uses, shows Visual Studio 2013/2015/2017/2019 are usable in the System Requirements section (middle of page). Visual Studio 2022 is not shown in that section and so it's reasonable to assume that it will not work or has not been test for this purpose as of yet.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 6):

vs2022

disk:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.32.31326/bin/Hostx64/x64/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).